# esp32 and the esp32-cam (agoal)

Tags: esp32, proximity, ble

Is it considered possible to use the esp32 code on an esp32 cam board? Do they use the same hardware? I am having difficulty using this sketch https://gist.github.com/wybiral/2a96c1d1605af7efa11b690586c4b13e on my esp32 cam and I think it is because it was designed for an esp32 board.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: what difficulty?

Comment: are you implying they should be compatible? @Juraj I am having difficulty with the board locking up and not being able to program it anymore. That is another issue I am still dealing with. I am new to arduino and cant understand it. I explain that issue here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/66402/stuck-with-bad-sketch

Comment: StackExchange is not for troubleshooting. stop asking the same question again and again and discussing in comments. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour